Area of Cyclic polygons
Can we generalize /extend Brahmagupta's formula to find the area of  cyclic pentagons, hexagons, $n$ sided polygons $n>3$ ? For example
$$ 2s= (a+b+c+d+e), \Delta=\sqrt{s (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)(s-e)}; $$
Since there is ambiguity of connecting the sides serially how can all combination configurations be included in the same formula for $n>3$?

Compared to the first figure, the second figure circum-circle radius, sides 1,2 are scaled keeping sides 3,4 same length.

It would be better to limit yourself to convex polygons for this problem. On the other hand, it is almost certain that if the formula could be extended to polygons with more than 4 sides, it would have been discovered a long time ago.

In maths one seeks to find  results for all comprehensive configurational arrangements. ( Edited pic to include a third case),  the self non convex double triangle is also a candidate with its area evaluable perhaps with consideration of direction reversals around circle center.

Note that the formula for triangle employs $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$ not $s=a+b+c$ as you wrote.

Thanks, corrected the typo.
